# Connection error when configuring Microsoft velocity

Tags: sql, appfabric

I am trying to install Microsoft velocity on a machine that will use a sql database for it's configuration store.

I have entered the connection string correctly but when I test the connection it fails, here are the logs:

2009-01-23 11:54:30.03 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.
2009-01-23 11:54:30.03 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. [CLIENT: xxx.xx.xx.xxx]

Which implies that the login is valid but the connection failed along the way, can anybody help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Microsoft Project Code Named "Velocity" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx

Answer (score 1):

'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' would indicate that the account you used to login was not identified in SQL Server.  You need to make sure that the account is listed in the security and has rights to the database you want to connect.